# My Prefab disappears from script when I run the game?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d

I have Script attached on my Player, that script has Public GameObject variable.When I attach my Prefab to it and run game it disappears from script ?

I add my prefab to script

[image]

When I run the game it just disappears !!??

[image]

Comment: Can you provide the script?

Comment: It's ok now, I found another way of solving this problem.. Thanks to everybody :D

Answer (score 1):

the bomb prefab that you attach must be in under your asset folder , not in the scene , I mean when you click on the bomb that you assigned it must open project tab and shows it to you if it only exist in scene , it will be disappeared

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the bomb prefab you are assigning to your public GameObject variable is somehow being destroyed when you start the game.

For example:

```
public GameObject other;

private void Awake()
    {
        Destroy(other);
    }
```

Check to see if you have any Destroy functions that could be causing the prefab to be destroyed.

Comment: No , I don't have anything like that :D

Comment: Along the lines of what Christopher said about it being destroyed, do you by any chance attempt to initialize the bomb prefab in your start or awake method? Like this bomb = ....